# Are python's popen (and similar) functions affected by Shellshock?

Tags: shellshock, python

Basically which python's functions trigger bash (and might be impacted by shellshock), and which don't ?

I have come up with this question by seeing in some scripts the `popen()` function.

My question relates to both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I believe if you have `shell=True` it would still be vulnerable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Any* program that, at some point, calls `bash` is affected. In particular the [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) function is vulnerable *if the system has `bash` as `/bin/sh`*, so any program calling it (or some equivalent) is vulnerable too.

The `popen` functions *can* be vulnerable, depending on the arguments passed. Quoting from the documentation:

> Also, for each of these variants, on Unix, `cmd` may be a sequence, in
>   which case arguments will be passed directly to the program without
>   shell intervention (as with [`os.spawnv()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.spawnl)). If `cmd` is a string it will
>   be passed to the shell (as with [`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system)).

to my understanding this means that calls like:

```
os.popenx(['executable', 'some', 'arguments'])
```

are safe because no shell is invoked, while commands of the form:

```
os.popenx('executable some argument')
```

are vulnerable because a shell will be used to interpret the string as a command line.

Also note that *all* `popen` functions are deprecated since python2.6 and should have been avoided since then. The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module provides a much better interface to launching subprocesses which is shellshock safe by default. If you don't pass the `shell=True` argument your program wont launch subshells and hence wont be affected by shellshock.

---

To safely use `subprocess` you should avoid using the `shell=True` argument as much as you can (this was true even before the discovery of shellshock and is already well documented as a security hazard anyway).

In particular, if you want to simply launch an executable use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(['executable name', 'arg1', '--opt1', 'opt-arg', ...])
```

if you don't want to write the list of strings by hand you can rely on the `shlex` module:

```
subprocess.call(shlex.split('executable-name arg1 "quoted arguments are correctly handled" etc'))
```

If you want to retrieve the output of the command use [`check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) instead of `call`.

If you want to run a pipeline of commands like `cmd1 | cmd2 | cmd3` you can still avoid launching a shell:

```
cmd1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1_command_line, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2_command_line, stdin=cmd1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd3 = subprocess.Popen(cmd3_command_line, stdin=cmd2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Use `shell=True` only if strictly necessary, and in such a case consider explicitly passing the environment to the shell using the `env` argument.

Comment: Exactly for what I was looking for: with examples when shell is and not invoked. I liked your writting that you madenit educational for readers soncan serve as reference!

Comment: Even if *you* avoid executing bash, you're still in trouble if the program you run decides to execute bash itself. It's difficult to be 100% certain you're safe.

Comment: @MattNordhoff Actually, as I mentioned in the end, you *can* be safe in that case by providing the `env` parameter to the `subprocess`'s functions. In this way the subprocesses don't inherit the current environment. It shouldn't be hard to write a very simple function that makes a copy of the current environment removing variables whose value looks suspicious, in this way the subprocesses could still have access to the original environment, but without the danger of executing arbitrary code.

Comment: Why `check_output` instead of `call`? Just curious.

Comment: @Bepetersn I don't understand your question. `call` and `check_output` do two different things. If you want to retrieve the output of a command in the form of a string that's exactly what `check_output` is for. See the examples in the documentation. `call` only executes the command, without returning its output.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, popen is affected by ShellShock.  However, I do not have a comprehensive list to provide you - anything that is backed by a call to /bin/bash (such as a call to /bin/sh which links to /bin/bash - which is assumed in the below quote) is vulnerable.

> A range of web apps written in PHP, Python, C++ or Java could be
>   vulnerable if they use calls to functions such as popen() or system(),
>   as these are backed by calls to /bin/sh -c in turn, Zalewski notes.

http://www.itnews.com.au/News/396256,further-flaws-render-shellshock-patch-ineffective.aspx

I hope this provides you a sufficient interim response to your question.

Comment: Good answer but /bin/sh is not always actually just a link to /bin/bash thus /bin/bash would be a better reference check http://askubuntu.com/questions/141928/what-is-difference-between-bin-sh-and-bin-bash

Comment: True, I updated it to be a little more clear.